# Is there any way to get the array length inside a mapping without a getter function or count variable?

Tags: web3js, dapps, react, mapping

```
mapping(address => uint256[]) public submitterAddressToFormIdsAssigned;
```

This is a mapping from an address to an array of uint256s.

I want to get the length of array. I used a count variable before but because contract size exceeded the maximum limit allowed, I had to remove it. How can I get the array length in my dApp? I am using Web3.js

Comment: Do you want the length inside the contract or in your front-end application?

Comment: Hi @ShubhamSharma , I am building a DApp . I need the array length in frontend . I am using web3.js for interaction .

Comment: You can directly call the function `submitterAddressToFormIdsAssigned` inside your application. It will return the arrays attached to this mapping. And through that getting length won't be a hard task.

Comment: This does not work bro . I got a similar error in another public mapping . submitSignedPDF error : Error: Invalid number of parameters for "adminAddressToFormIdsCreated". Got 1 expected 2!
    at Object.InvalidNumberOfParams (errors.js:33:1)
    at y._createTxObject (index.js:695:1)
    at eWarrant.js:1253:1 . Here adminAddressToFormIdsCreated is a mapping similar to the submitterAddressToFormIdsAssigned mapping . [ mapping(address => uint256[]) public adminAddressToFormIdsCreated; ]